# Python - Append items to a list while making https requests inside a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-requests, spotipy

I am making requests to `SPotify API` inside a `for loop`, like so:

```
track_ids = []
#get track_ids
for track in random.sample(pitchfork_tracks, 10):
    results = sp.search(q=track, type='track') #here I call Spotify endpoint
    items = results['tracks']['items']
    for t in items:
        track_ids.append(t['uri'])
return track_ids
```

I can `print` every `t` alright, but if I try to `return` `track_ids`, console returns me nothing.

Log tells me:

```
2016-10-03 23:55:49 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): accounts.spotify.com
2016-10-03 23:55:50 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: "POST /api/token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2016-10-03 23:55:50 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.spotify.com
2016-10-03 23:55:50 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: "GET /v1/search?q=Rushes&limit=10&type=track&offset=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2016-10-03 23:55:50 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.spotify.com
2016-10-03 23:55:51 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: "GET /v1/search?q=Opposite+House&limit=10&type=track&offset=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2016-10-03 23:55:51 [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool] INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.spotify.com
```

it looks like starting and ending connections over and over has something to do with it...or am I missing something obvious here?

how can I solve this and manage to build my `track_ids` `list`?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What do you get in return and what are you expecting? What do you get when you print `t`?

Comment: What means "it doesn't work." ?

Comment: Did you try printing/logging in your loop to see what the data looks like that you are dealing with?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I get no output.

Comment: what output ? `return` doesn't create output.

Comment: @furas I can't see the contents of `track_ids`, if there is any.

Comment: `return` returns value from function and then you can assign it to variable or you can print it - do you print it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`track_ids` scope is inside your function. To print list you can do like this

```
track_ids = yourfunction()
print track_ids
```

OR

you can make `track_ids` list global and declare it outside of your function.